# How to resume a timeout after restarting a bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm just looking for a way to resume a timeout after the bot restart or crash.
Is there any node package for that? Or any method?

I'm hosting on Glitch, so there is always a chance that the bot restart.
This is my code:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    let users = m.reactions.get("").users
    let gFilter = users.filter(u => !u.bot).random()
    giveEmbed.title = null
    giveEmbed.description = null
    giveEmbed.fields = [{
        name: ' Giveaway Ended! ',
        value: `**Winner :** ${gFilter}\n**Prize :** ${title}`,
        inline: false
    }]
    giveEmbed.timestamp = new Date()
    giveEmbed.footer = ({
        text: `Ended At`
    })
    if (!gFilter) {
        giveEmbed.fields = [{
            name: ' Giveaway Ended! ',
            value: `**Winner :** No Winner\n**Prize :** ${title}`,
            inline: false
        }]
        m.edit('** GIVEAWAY ENDED  @everyone**', {
            embed: giveEmbed
        });
        message.guild.channels.get(room.replace(/\D/g, '')).send(`**The Giveaway Ended With No Winner **`)
    } else {
        m.edit('** GIVEAWAY ENDED  @everyone**', {
            embed: giveEmbed
        });
        message.guild.channels.get(room.replace(/\D/g, '')).send(`**Congratulations ${gFilter} ! You Won The __${title}__ !!! <a:crazy:526018890208116738>**`)
        gFilter.send(`**Congratulations ${gFilter} ! You Won The __${title}__ !!! <a:crazy:526018890208116738>\nAsk for Your Prize In <#593334823230242817> <a:RainbowParrot:597540860934225960>**`)
    }
}, ms(duration));
```

Comment: If the scripts restarts, you need to store something in the file system (or database). I would say the timestamp of the timeout planed end. Then when the bot restarts, look for that file, and create a new timeout that should resolve at the recovered timestamp.

Comment: Local file like .json? or even a Discord text channel?
That's a good idea, but about the database, its complicated :o

Comment: I suggested database in case you already had one. But yes, you can use a JSON file. A message in a discord channel could work too, but could be unnecessary complicated.

Comment: I was, I'm not using DBs for now

Comment: as @Seblor said use a db or json files (anything extern to your program). And load it at the beginning of your giveaway, and then edit the file **and** the variable in your program. This way, if it's stop, when it will restart, it's just gonna load the file/db/..., and it will be as nothing happened

Comment: ok, i will try that